# handle updating complex objects in a child component when some properties might be undefined (svelte)

Tags: svelte

I have an object with some nested properties that might not be present (it is a settings object for new features). I would like to edit these properties so I have a parent component that passes the data to a child that handles the actual changes. I don't know how to do it.

Repl with one of the non-working solutions (no. 4)
https://svelte.dev/repl/5346d4d9a6814a7e96ce25e20b5efe56?version=4.1.2

This is a simplified example:

```html
// Parent.svelte
<script>
const objects = [
  { 'name: 'a', 'props': { color: 'blue' } },
  { 'name: 'b' }, // missing 'props'
]
let selectedObj
</script>

{#each objects as o}
  <button on:click={() => selectedObj = o}>{o.name}</button>
{/each}

{#if selectedObj}
  <Edit obj={selectedObj} />
{/if}
```

```html
// Edit.svelte
<script>
  export let obj
</script>

Set color: <input bind:value={obj.props.color}>
```

1. I could bind the selectedObj in the parent (`<Edit bind:obj={selectedObj} />`) to streamline it, but then the `obj.props.color` will throw an undefined error when not present (for the second object)
2. I cannot use `obj.props?.color` and bind at the same time
3. I tried to create another variable that would copy (parts of) `obj` in the child, but then it will either not be reactive

```js
let color = obj.props?.color // won't update color when selecting objects
```

4. or it won't let me update it at all (I guess it keeps recomputing the original value)

```js
// it updates the color upon selecting objects, but won't let me update the input anymore.
$: color = obj.props.color
<input bind:value={color}>
```

Is there something I am missing here? The only idea I have at the moment is to sanitize the object and make sure all the bound values are present. But that is not very convenient and is rather complicated. I like these objects stored with only explicitly "defined" props (as not every object needs complex settings for features they are not even utilizing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could e.g. use `bind:obj` and wrap things that could be undefined inside the component with an `{#if obj.property != null}`; this would of course remove the input entirely.

Another approach if direct bindings are not possible is usually to split it into data in & event out. E.g. inside the component:

```html
<input value={obj.props?.color} on:input={e => ...}>
```

In the event handler you could then create a `props` object if there is not one already and set the value from `e.currentTarget.value`.

(This can also be done with components and custom [component events](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte#createeventdispatcher).)

Comment: Yes, thanks, I guess this is a great solution - to use the one way binding and event handlers.